# replce value of column in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am working with phpmyadmin. I have one table `log` in phpmyadmin. I would like to change a value in one column. If I add new value, it must show me `Arbeitsplatz 1` instead of `1` in the `Station` column.

This is my `log` table. In the third column I would like to replace values for every new entry. For example, if the new value is `3` in `station` column, it should show me `Arbeitsplatz 3` in the `log` table. If it is `4`, then `Arbeitsplatz 4` and so on.

[image: log table]

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to change the column datatype from integer to varchar first, then update that row:

```
update `log` set `Station` = CONCAT('Arbeitsplatz ', `Station`);
```

But first, back up that table just in case something fails...

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. This Command can affect only existing data. But i would like to change every time. when Data comes. For example if i get Station value 3 then it should automatic convert Arbeitsplatz3. Is this possible?

Comment: The best solution, in my opinion, would be to have whatever front end you're using insert the proper data in the first place. If that's not an option, you could use a stored procedure to handle the insert (you could even build this to accept "Arbeitsplatz 3" or "3" and insert the correct data either way), or you could simply store the data as "3" and make the CONCAT part of your select query when displaying the data. If you're convinced you need to store the "Arbeitsplatz " portion in the database and can't change the front-end, the stored procedure is probably best.

Comment: i can't change data. Which is inserted in table because data comes automatic from sensors. So i must adjust something in table. If i use Stored procedure. I must execute procedure every time. Whenever the data has been updated. Can i solve tis problem with help of trigger? Can  i use CONCAT Funktion in trigger?

Comment: Yes, you can use concat in trigger, but maybe you shouldn't. I don't know how this data is used, but you can also 'fix' this in the presentation (select queries) instead of storing it in the database. As it is a constant value, it will only consume disk space.